# Releasing connection in android

Tags: android, httpclient, illegalstateexception

I have only one **httpclient** in my 1st activity which is used in all other activities.Because I am using **PHP Sessions**.

In my 1st Activity I have a listview which takes 4-5 secs to load items
 (which will be done by a connection to the server), and in the same activity I have a search field...which on button click takes me to a searchActivity where using same httpclient search results will be loaded in a different listview.
My problem is during the 4-5 sec load time in the 1st activity if I try to search something, my app crashes saying:

> > Invalid use of **SingleClientConnManager**: connection still allocated.

Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

> > **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No wrapped connection.**

and eventually a null pointer exception later

I think as I am using the same httpclient in the searchActivity before completing the 1st Activity is creating this error (correct me if am wrong)

so if my assumption is right how can i release this connection in the intent where i am moving to searchAvtivity from 1st activity??

Thank you

CODE:

```
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                SignUpActivity.url+"/feed/fetchfeed");
        httppost.setHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH", "xmlhttprequest");
        httppost.setHeader("MOBILE_DATA_REQUESTED", "mobileHttpRequest");
        HttpResponse response = SignUpActivity.httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.d("response", "" + response);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        Log.d("entity", "" + entity);
        is = entity.getContent();

        Log.d("is", "" + is);

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            Log.d("sb", "" + sb);
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.d("result", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error3", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        Log.e("response", "response is:" + response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error4", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Log.d("JArray", "entered try");
        JArray = new JSONArray(result);
        feed_products_list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Log.d("JArray", "try last line");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("JArray", "in catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObj;
    JSONObject jsonObjStore;
    JSONObject jsonObjUser;

    for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            Log.d("jsonObj",
                    "entered try" + " " + i + " " + JArray.length());
            jsonObj = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            jsonObjUser = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("jsonObj", "in catch");
            continue;
        }

        try {
            Log.d("feed_products_list", "entered try");
            Log.d("type of action", jsonObj.getString("action"));
            if (jsonObj.getString("action").equals("entry")) {
                Log.d("if block", "entered block 'entry'");

                jsonObjStore = jsonObj.getJSONObject("store");
                Log.d("store", jsonObjStore.getString("name"));

                feed_products_list.add(new Product(jsonObj.getInt("id"),
                        jsonObj.getString("action"), jsonObj
                                .getString("image"), jsonObj
                                .getString("product_name"), jsonObj
                                .getString("reported_price_formated"),
                        jsonObjStore.getString("name"), jsonObjStore
                                .getString("area"), jsonObjStore
                                .getString("city"), jsonObj
                                .getString("mrp"), jsonObjUser
                                .getString("name"), jsonObj
                                .getLong("reported_timestamp"), jsonObj
                                .getInt("discount"), jsonObjStore
                                .getDouble("lat"), jsonObjStore
                                .getDouble("lng")));

                Log.d("store id", jsonObjStore.getString("id"));
                Log.d("feed_products_list product: ",
                        feed_products_list.get(i).lat + "   "
                                + feed_products_list.get(i).lng);

            } else if (jsonObj.getString("action").equals("contest")) {
                Log.d("if block", "entered block 'contest'");
                feed_products_list.add(new Product(jsonObj.getInt("id"),
                        jsonObj.getString("action"), jsonObjUser
                                .getString("image"), jsonObj
                                .getString("product_name"), jsonObj
                                .getString("city"), jsonObjUser
                                .getString("name"), jsonObj
                                .getLong("reported_timestamp")));

                Log.d("feed_products_list",
                        feed_products_list.get(i).productName);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    m = 1;
}
```

I added this:

```
                try {
                    is.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(FeedListViewActivity.this,
                            SearchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("onClick", search_string);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

but i got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection are automatically closed if you close the `InputStream`'s you get from httpclient. Check your code and make sure you are closing them properly.

Comment: you mean in the intent i need to close the InputStream before starting the intent??

Comment: actually right now i am closing the InputStream after fetching all the required data (during that 4-5 sec load time)

Comment: You are either not reading the whole content or are calling the same httpclient instance from two different threads.

Comment: but in the "added this" code i am definitely closing InputStream right??? but in the processing of reading data using an IS if i close it before complete data is fetched...does that gives an error???

Comment: Try commenting out the `is.close()`.

Comment: in the "added this" code??....thats what it used to be before posting this question...i added that line when u said httpclient automatically closes when IS is closed.

Comment: The way it works is this: you need read all the data from stream for connection to be freed. For some reason you are not. Are you getting any errors/exceptions? Try replacing your `while` loop with `String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity)`, that should do the right thing, e.g., read all the data and close the stream.

Comment: you mean close the stream only when all the data is read???....if so yeah i am doing that...the problem is that, before all the data is read(takes 4-5 secs) if i use search it needs the same httpclient, here is where i get error "release the connection before allocating another one"

Comment: The underlying connection is only released after you read all the data. You probably don't want to do two network operations simultaneously. Either wait for the first one to finish, or use `AndroidHttpClient`, it should handle this better. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html